# How to expose prometheus using ingress?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

Im new to kubernetes. Im using prometheus-community/prometheus helm chart form [prometheus-community](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus). Inside the chart there are options to set up ingress using the chart values see them [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus?modal=values-schema). I deployed helm using this new values:

```
# Custom values for Prometheus Helm chart
rbac:
  create: true

podSecurityPolicy:
  enabled: false

server:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - staging.lan
    path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
# Other values
```

But It seams I can't access the prometheus at staging.lan/prometheus/. It seams all the pods are ok and I can use prometheus if I expose a port from the service or the pod but not while using ingress provided from the helm chart.
What should i change in the values in order to expose prometheus using ingress.

Comment: There is a whole lot of things that could be wrong in a case like this, which is hard to help with without a lot more information. But to debug it I would initially check the Ingress resource that is created, to make sure it looks correct as well as checking the logs of the ingress controller and see if it shows any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing rewrite-target annotations for ingress.
So, `ingress` will be like this:

```
# Custom values for Prometheus Helm chart
rbac:
  create: true

podSecurityPolicy:
  enabled: false

server:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    hosts:
      - staging.lan
    path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
# Other values
```